# PHP Timezones with minutes different than "00" or "30" or "45" in old dates

Tags: php, timezone

I'm working on a system that needs to deal with records in the database that involve a series of very old periods, and I ended up with a problem related to timezones.

From what I searched, there are only timezones that have the values "00", "30" or "45" in the  minutes (https://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones-interesting.html). However, when we are going to parse very old dates, it seems that the timezone is shifted in some way, perhaps in an attempt to correct the time.

Code:

```
<?php
$timezones = timezone_identifiers_list();
foreach ($timezones as $k => $tz) {
    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
    echo $tz . ' - ' . \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '1900-01-01 00:00:00')->format(DATE_ATOM) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Some examples of what returns:

- Africa/Addis_Ababa - 1900-01-01T00:00:00+02:**27**
- America/Argentina/San_Luis - 1900-01-01T00:00:00-04:**16**
- America/Bahia_Banderas - 1900-01-01T00:00:00-07:**01**
- America/Sao_Paulo - 1900-01-01T00:00:00-03:**06**
- Asia/Kuala_Lumpur - 1900-01-01T00:00:00+06:**46**
- Europe/Athens - 1900-01-01T00:00:00+01:**34**
- Europe/Dublin - 1900-01-01T00:00:00-00:**25**

Anyone could tell us what is happening??

Thanks!

Comment: Time(stamp) starts counting at 1970-01-01.

Comment: @MarkusZeller, although I don't think it is related to this question directly, in PHP a timestamp is either a 32 or 64 bit number according to the [docs](https://www.php.net/strtotime). "The valid range of a timestamp is typically from Fri, 13 Dec 1901 20:45:54 UTC to Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 UTC. (These are the dates that correspond to the minimum and maximum values for a 32-bit signed integer.)" It is a different function, but still a timestamp.

Comment: @chuckedw, as Sammitch mentions in their answer, timezones getting really finicky the farther back you go. For instance, if you focus on just Africa/Addis_Abada, you'd find that in [1936 they shifted 24 minutes and 40 seconds into the future](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/ethiopia?year=1936).

Comment: And, same location, [something happened in 1908 as April turned to May](https://3v4l.org/LEkIO)

Answer (score 3):

Timezones weren't "a thing" until late in the 19th century, and even then it wasn't likely to be a rigid set of round, 1-hour offsets unless you had something like a geographically massive rail system you were trying to coordinate, like the US had.

Most localities simply set their time offset in accordance to what their days actually were or whatever offset the nearest astronomical observatory used, hence the strange offsets.

The rules and history that govern timekeeping are bafflingly broad, complex, and frequently petty. This is why we have Date/Time libraries and `/usr/share/zoneinfo` with 1788 config files.

Comment: Just to add to this, most time zones entries in the tzdb start with an `LMT` entry, which represents the [Local Mean Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_mean_time) at city which represents the time zone.  The assumption is that before recorded time zones, people who may have been in that area aligned their concept of time to the sun's position in the sky overhead.  Though if you go back far enough that isn't even true, as some civilizations may have just thought of time in large vague segments, such as "early morning", "late afternoon", etc.  The word "midnight" didn't always mean 12am.